# Having trouble understanding how HStack content works with fluid widths

Tags: swiftui, hstack

I've been running into a pretty consistent problem with how views inside `HStack` work, with a simplified screenshot to exemplify the issue.

My expectation would be for the width of the green to basically be (expressed like an equation):

`Section.width` - `Image.width`

The section width is fluid, and the image width is explicit. Surely that means the green should be correctly calculated?

Any help with what seems to be a basic misunderstanding on my part would be hugely appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you're right, but there are just default List/Form insets, which can be either changed or removed.

So all you need is

[image: demo1]

that gives on Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo2]

Comment: Since this solved my problem specifically, I'll give you the answer. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The height property in your frame for the image is messing with width dimensions. By setting the maxHeight to be infinity, the height property will expand the image to the max possible height, meaning the height of the section, even if it changes the width. You can think of it as, in a way, overriding the ability of the text to stretch its full width.

To fix this, consider changing the maxHeight property by adding a set height, or play around with different types of frames dimensions.

I know this doesn't talk about HStack's specifically, but feel free to check out this video to learn more about layout: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zczHBLtpRZo

If you want to launch an app on the app store, you may want to consider learning Geometry Reader to have dynamic dimensions across different screen sizes. This is a tutorial from a really good website, hacking with swift: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNO1b58k7zg&t=505s